# File not found error (MVC Controller image.fromfile)

Tags: model-view-controller, controller

I have a view and controller. view has a bootstrap button for select an image file. image file can be anywhere on disk or network.

filedialog windows opens when i clicked button and i can select an image file for post to controller.

controller changing this image file to image

```
system.drawing.image.fromfile("myimagepath");
```

It's working good when test it from debug (or publish project to same code server)

But it doesn't working on other servers. (example: A server)

Publishin my project to A server and opening ("https://a/myproject") and selecting an image from other location (From B server) with fileopendialog and posting it to controller.

Controller says ("file not found") on

```
system.drawing.image.fromfile("myimagepath")
```

line. but file exists. A server can access to B server from operating system and i can see all content of B server without any problem. (also i can select image from B server already)

What can i do?

Thanks inadvance

Answer (score 0):

ok. solved my problem.

changed

```
system.drawing.image.fromfile("myimagepath")
```

to

```
system.drawing.image.fromfile(myimage.inputstream)
```